# WordPress не понимает <?php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Возникла следующая проблема.

Пытаюсь на главной странице в самописной теме WordPress вывести последние записи (из блога).

Когда я пишу html в файле index.php, все работает. Но когда я переношу код в редактор страниц в панели администратора, то происходит такое.

В чем может быть причина, куда копать?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rty7i.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyxFi.jpg)

```
    <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
      <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>
      <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 blog_card">
        <div class="single-blog-1 card">
            <div class="single-blog-img">
              <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail(array(360, 224),array("class"=>"alignleft post_thumbnail"));} ?>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-meta-1">
              <span class="date-type-1">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><a class="date"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></a>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-text-1 card-body">
                <h4>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h4>
                <p>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <span>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-ready-1">Читать далее</a>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: на скрине видно, что `class="` редактор заменил на class= **>>**

Comment: Могу дать совет, но не точно, попробуйте заэкранировать проблемные участки. `class=\"\"`

Comment: Не понял куда Вы это все вставляете, но:
1. В WP нельзя вставлять php код в контент записи/страницы.
2. Если Вы можете редактировать index.php то  в чем проблема отредактировать соответствующий темплейт темы ?

Comment: @NikPashchuk Спасибо за ответ. Насчёт того, что нельзя вставлять php в контент страницы, я уже понял, но как быть иначе, если главная страница из админки выбирается только среди этих страниц?

Comment: @foreigndezigner Довольно таки просто: 1. В корне темы создаеш файл с любым названием, например example.php 2. Пишеш в нем /* Template Name: Мой супер темплейт */ 3. В админке создаеш новую Page и выбираеш к ней темплейт справа на сайдбаре "Мой супер темплейт" , при этом в файл php темплейта добавляеш свой код. Далее при переходе на страницу которую Вы создали в п3 будет отображатся код с темплейта(файла). Далее, если нужно, можно поставить созданную страницу как главную на сайте через настройки, чтение(где Homepage селект).

Comment: @NikPashchuk должно помочь, спасибо, чуть позже попробую, отпишусь!

Comment: @foreigndezigner или, запихнуть даный код в Шорткод, при этом будет возможность вызывать даную "смесь кода" в контенте записи через, например "[выведи мой код]". 
Вариантов очень много, но так как в вопросе не описано для чего это нужно(использывать разово или множество раз) и решения разные

Comment: @NikPashchuk 1-й вариант подошел - быстро решил проблему! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помог @NikPashchuk

1. В корне темы создаешь файл с любым названием, например example.php
2. Пишешь в нем /* Template Name: Мой супер темплейт */
3. В админке создаешь новую Page и выбираешь к ней темплейт справа на сайдбаре "Мой супер темплейт" , при этом в файл php темплейта добавляешь свой код. Далее при переходе на страницу которую Вы создали в п3 будет отображается код с темплейта (файла). Далее, если нужно, можно поставить созданную страницу как главную на сайте через настройки, чтение (где Homepage селект).

Или, запихнуть даный код в Шорткод, при этом будет возможность вызывать даную "смесь кода" в контенте записи через, например "[выведи мой код]". Вариантов очень много, но так как в вопросе не описано для чего это нужно(использывать разово или множество раз) и решения разные